# Как вывести результат из массива? php

Tags: php, массивы, vkontakte-api

Нужно вывести максимальные размер изображений.

Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [count] => 25
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 456240343
                            [album_id] => 251671826
                            [owner_id] => -12465617
                            [user_id] => 23350658
                            [sizes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => m
                                            [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9edde/0k4dCRYLfp4.jpg
                                            [width] => 130
                                            [height] => 67
                                        )

```
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => o
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9ede1/B4cv0GZIuWo.jpg
                                        [width] => 130
                                        [height] => 87
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => p
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9ede2/gAG197_nxY0.jpg
                                        [width] => 200
                                        [height] => 133
                                    )

                                [3] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => q
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9ede3/lIkPkl5CCws.jpg
                                        [width] => 320
                                        [height] => 213
                                    )

                                [4] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => r
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9ede4/c6HJmQz9t7c.jpg
                                        [width] => 510
                                        [height] => 340
                                    )

                                [5] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => s
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9eddd/8AW6KHFjbP0.jpg
                                        [width] => 75
                                        [height] => 39
                                    )

                                [6] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => x
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9eddf/t1iud2lvTCw.jpg
                                        [width] => 604
                                        [height] => 313
                                    )

                                [7] => Array
                                    (
                                        [type] => y
                                        [url] => https://pp.userapi.com/c830708/v830708599/9ede0/Xa4QQrry2_Y.jpg
                                        [width] => 768
                                        [height] => 398
                                    )

                            )

                        [text] => 
                        [date] => 1520606924
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Имеем идентичный массив вашего формата:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        'type' => 'a',
        'width' => 130,
        'height' => 170
    ],
    1 => [
        'type' => 'b',
        'width' => 170,
        'height' => 120
    ],
];
```

Воспользуемся функцией `array_reduce`

```
$data = array_reduce($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    return bcadd($a['width'], $a['height']) > bcadd($b['width'], $b['height']) ? $a : $b;
});
```

**faq**: 
Используем функцию `bcadd` для сложения высоты и длины изображения и получаем общее число, которое далее сравниваем с другими.

Выводим результат на экран

`print_r($data);`

Получаем массив, с самым большим форматом изображения

```
Array
(
    [type] => a
    [width] => 130
    [height] => 170
)
```